# PHP Fatal error: Class 'CI_DB_postgre_driver' not found in system/database/DB.php on line 144 - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, postgresql, fatal-error

I'm working with CodeIgniter and when I try to connect to a PostgreSQL database with

```
$this->load->database();
```

it show me a blank page. In the Apache log, I see the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_DB_postgre_driver' not found in system/database/DB.php on line 144

autoload line: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Here's my `database.php`:

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'user';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Do you have a proper configuration for your DB?

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: Yes, i checked my configuration and the version of CodeIgniter is 2.1.4

Comment: did you load database in autoload.php

Comment: Yes i did, i don't kwnow what's the problem.

Comment: Can you post your autoload line, as well as your database config settings?

Comment: This is the autoload: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
And the file database.php: http://pastebin.com/hXKy3xpr

Comment: Does `system/database/drivers/postgre/postgre_driver.php` exist? (EDIT: Wait, if it didn't, it would fail on line 140. Did you rename the class?)

Comment: Yes, postgre_driver.php exist.

Comment: And the class CI_DB_postgre_driver is defined within it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have [eval()](http://php.net/eval) function disabled:

```
var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));
```